# C# DateTime format with input from a string

Tags: c#, datetime, format

What I have:

```
string format = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff";

string eventdatetime = "2013.07.12 15:32:04:4687";
```

What I need to do is to take the eventdatetime string and put it into a DateTime variable, lets call it "x". And it needs to be in the format yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff". Don't know if it is right but it should look like this: "2013.07.12 15:32:04:4687". It dosent work with:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(eventdatetime, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anyone knows? I keep getting the AM/PM and wrong order. Wich tells me that the format didnt work.

Comment: Just a simple "spelling" mistake on your end - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17674608/1185053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DateTime` has no format. It just represents a date and a time. If you want to *display* it in a specific format, convert it back to a `string` with the appropriate format specifiers:

```
string format = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff";
string eventdatetime = "2013.07.12 15:32:04:4687";
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(eventdatetime, format,
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var display = x.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff");
```

Furthermore, `zzzz` designates the timezone. You want `ffff` which designates fractions of a second.

Comment: Ah, that's why. Then I have to go around my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`z` is for UTC offset, not fractions of a second. Use `f` instead. [See MSDN documentation for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
string format = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff";
```